# Idiorm/Paris - Access to junction table's columns

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, has-many-through, idiorm

I'm using Paris for my new project...

Let's say I have 3 tables: users, books and borrows:

users: id/name

books: id/title

borrows: users_id/books_id/borrow_date/return_date

---

In Books class:

```
function users()
{
    return $this->has_many_through('Users', 'Borrows');
}
```

In Users class:

```
function books()
{
    return $this->has_many_through('User', 'Borrows');
}
```

Everything is fine, I can access to borrowed books by each user and list of users who borrowed a single book before, but I'm wondering that how can I access to `borrow_date` and `return_date` column/property of Borrows table/class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Idiorm ([the Paris brother](http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/)).

`User` model:

```
<?php
class User extends Model {
    public static $_table = 'Users';
    public static $_id_column = 'id';

    function books()
    {
        return $this->has_many_through('User', 'Borrow');
    }

    public static function findBooksAndBorrows($id) {
        return ORM::for_table('Users')
            ->join('Borrows', array('Users.id', '=', 'Borrows.users_id'))
            ->join('Books', array('Borrows.books_id', '=', 'Books.id'));
    } 
}
```

In your code:

```
$booksAndBorrows = User::findBooksAndBorrows(1)->find_array();
echo json_encode($booksAndBorrows);
```